# Removing elements in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dict = {'name': ['bob', 'bob, 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
```

If the elements in the list is equal to the specified value, keep that element, else
if it does not equal to the specified value remove that element at that index in every key. *Without the use of imports*

Ex:

```
>>> dict = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(dict, 'name', 'bob')
dict = {'name': ['bob', 'bob'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff']}

>>> dict = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(dict, 'name', 'jeff')
dict = {'name': ['jeff'], 'last': ['jones']}

process_dict(dict, key, value):
    pass


>>> dict = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(dict, 'name', 'bob')
```

The specified key is 'name' and the specified value is 'bob', so we look at the key, 'name' iterate through the values
and see if the element is equal to the specified value, if it is, than continue to the next key, and if it isn't
remove the value at that index in every key

So,

The first element in 'name' is 'bob' it is equal to the specified value, so we skip it, the next element is 'bob' as well
so we skip it, the next element after that does not equal to the specified value so we remove every element in each key at that index,

we now get:

```
{'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'jones']}
```

The next element after that is 'jeff' which is also not equal to the specified value, so we so remove every element in each key at that index, we
now finally get:

```
{'name': ['bob', 'bob'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff']}
```

I am not to sure how to begin with this so I am in need of help

Comment: Begin with reading about [dict's interface.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Comment: Meta-advice: if you honestly couldn't write *anything* to address this problem then StackOverflow probably isn't the right forum.  We're really good at solving discrete problems, but we're not much good as a tutorial session.  For example, we tend to go for the best solution we can think of, and sometimes that isn't what you need.  I'd try to refresh yourself on simpler tasks first.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get a list of indexes where a match is found and then iterate over `dict.items()` and filter out all items that are not at those indexes.

```
def process_dict(d, k, v):
     indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(d[k]) if x==v] #indexes where a match is found
     return {k:[v[i] for i in indexes] for k, v in d.items()}
... 
>>> d = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(d, 'name', 'bob')
{'last': ['bob', 'jeff'], 'name': ['bob', 'bob']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a set of matching indices (produced with `enumerate()`, then select those indices when producing a new dictionary:

```
def process_dict(dct, key, value):
    indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(dct[key]) if v == value]
    return {key: [value[i] for i in indices] for key, value in dct.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> def process_dict(dct, key, value):
...     indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(dct[key]) if v == value]
...     return {key: [value[i] for i in indices] for key, value in dct.items()}
... 
>>> example1 = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(example1, 'name', 'bob')
{'last': ['bob', 'jeff'], 'name': ['bob', 'bob']}
>>> example2 = {'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'james', 'jeff'], 'last': ['bob', 'jeff', 'smith', 'jones']}
>>> process_dict(example2, 'name', 'jeff')
{'last': ['jones'], 'name': ['jeff']}
```

Comment: I was just toying with: `dict(zip(d.keys(), zip(*[val for key, val in zip(d['name'], zip(*d.values())) if key == 'bob'])))` - assumes equal length lists, but looks cooler :)